# Embedding a flv (or mp4) video using pdfTeX (plain TeX only)

Tags: pdftex, pdf, plain-tex, animations, embedding

I am attempting to find out how to embed a flv video in a pdf file created using plain TeX and pdfTeX.  I was successful at manually (via Adobe Acrobat's menu: Tools->Multimedia->Video Tool) embedding a flv video clip into an existing pdf.  Then examined the pdf file in a text editor (vim) to see if I could figure out the code that needed to be added to embed a video.  Although I was able to identify some of the lines associated with the embedding, I am clueless as to how to achieve the embedding using plain TeX and pdfTeX.  Would appreciate any pointers.

Thanks.

PS:  @AlexG 's response does give me what I was looking for.  However, I do have a follow up question.  I attempted to write the follow-up as a comment, but was not able to format the follow-up properly.  So here it is:

Toward the end of the code, what's the need for the "\setbox0=..." and the "\hbox to ..." lines?  Commenting these two lines did not seem to affect the solution:

```
top  

%\setbox0=\hbox{  }\immediate\pdfxform 0%  

\vbox to 25.6mm{%  
\pdfannot width \videowidth depth \videoheight height 0pt {  
  /Subtype/RichMedia  
  /BS <</W 0/S/S>>  
  /Contents (embedded video file:\videofile)  
  /NM (rma:\videofile)  
  /AP <</N \the\pdflastxform\space 0 R>>  
  /RichMediaSettings \the\pdflastobj\space 0 R  
  /RichMediaContent \rmcontent\space 0 R  
}}%  
%\hbox to \videowidth {\vbox to \videoheight {}\hss}%  

bottom
```

The above ending results in the video showing up placed vertically between the words top and bottom.

Comment: I'd keep the `\hbox to \videowidth {\vbox to \videoheight {}\hss}` line instead of enclosing `\pdfannot` in a `\vbox`. Otherwise, no horizontal space would be reserved for the  the video, and text following it on the same line would be obscured by the video.

Answer (score 10):

The following example defines `\embedvideo`. It uses the same media embedding method as the `media9` LaTeX package. Video files in the ***MP4/H264*** and ***FLV*** formats are played back within the video player component [VPlayer.swf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/media9/players/VPlayer.swf) shipping with `media9`.

See the [media9 manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/media9/doc/media9.pdf) on how to configure `VPlayer` via FlashVars, which are passed as the 3rd argument of `\embedvideo`.

The video player can be controlled by left mouse button press (pause) and release (play/resume), via the context menu accessed by right mouse button click and via the keyboard (see context menu for keys).

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%             
% \embedvideo{<width>}{<height>}{<flashvars>}{<video file (MP4+H264 or FLV)>}              
% flashvars documented in `texdoc media9`,  page 19                                        
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%             
\def\embedvideo#1#2#3#4{%                                                                  
  \ifdefined\vplayer\else%                                                                 
    \immediate\pdfobj stream file {VPlayer.swf}%                                           
    \immediate\pdfobj{<<                                                                   
      /Type/Filespec/F (VPlayer.swf)/UF (VPlayer.swf)                                      
      /EF <</F \the\pdflastobj\space 0 R>>                                                 
    >>}%                                                                                   
    \edef\vplayer{\the\pdflastobj}%                                                        
  \fi%                                                                                     
  %                                                                                        
  \immediate\pdfobj stream file {#4}%                                                      
  \immediate\pdfobj{<<                                                                     
    /Type/Filespec/F (#4)/UF (#4)                                                          
    /EF <</F \the\pdflastobj\space 0 R>>                                                   
  >>}%                                                                                     
  \edef\video{\the\pdflastobj}%                                                            
  %                                                                                        
  \immediate\pdfobj{<<                                                                     
    /Type/RichMediaInstance/Subtype/Video                                                  
    /Asset \vplayer\space 0 R                                                              
    /Params <</Binding/Foreground/FlashVars (source=#4&#3)>>                               
  >>}%                                                                                     
  %                                                                                        
  \immediate\pdfobj{<<                                                                     
    /Type/RichMediaConfiguration/Subtype/Video                                             
    /Instances [\the\pdflastobj\space 0 R]                                                 
  >>}%                                                                                     
  %                                                                                        
  \immediate\pdfobj{<<                                                                     
    /Type/RichMediaContent                                                                 
    /Assets <<                                                                             
      /Names [(VPlayer.swf) \vplayer\space 0 R (#4) \video\space 0 R]                      
    >>                                                                                     
    /Configurations [\the\pdflastobj\space 0 R]                                            
  >>}%                                                                                     
  \edef\rmcontent{\the\pdflastobj}%                                                        
  %                                                                                        
  \pdfobj{<<                                                                               
    /Activation <<                                                                         
      /Condition/PO                                                                        
      /Presentation <<                                                                     
        /Transparent true                                                                 
        /Style/Embedded                                                                    
        /PassContextClick true                                                            
      >>                                                                                   
    >>                                                                                     
    /Deactivation <</Condition/PC>>                                                        
  >>}%                                                                                     
  %                                                                                        
  \setbox0=\vbox to #2 {\vss\hbox to #1{\tt #4\hss}\vss}%
  \immediate\pdfxform 0%                                              
  %                                                                                        
  \pdfannot width #1 height #2 depth 0pt {                                                 
    /Subtype/RichMedia                                                                     
    /BS <</W 0/S/S>>                                                                       
    /Contents (embedded video file:#4)                                                     
    /NM (rma:#4)                                                                           
    /AP <</N \the\pdflastxform\space 0 R>>                                                 
    /RichMediaSettings \the\pdflastobj\space 0 R                                           
    /RichMediaContent \rmcontent\space 0 R                                                 
  }%                                                                                       
  \hbox to #1 {\vbox to #2 {}\hss}%                                                        
}%                                                                                         
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%             

Plain\TeX{} video example:                                                                

top

left\embedvideo{4cm}{3cm}{autoPlay=true&loop=true}{random.mp4}right                        

bottom
\bye
```

To answer the follow-up question:

The lines `\setbox0=...` and `\immediate\pdfxform 0%` produce a poster text for the inactive video. The text (video file name) is put in a box and subsequently distilled into a so-called Form-XObject. The latter is bound to the RichMedia annotation using the `/AP` entry. Without a poster text, AR displays an ugly box with a "?" inside if the video is inactive.

Comment: Follow up question written as post-script to original question.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation and source code of [`media9`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/media9) by Alexander Grahn is probably a good place to start. The documentation additionally contains a list of technical references at the end which you might also want to read.